# How to filter/block specific text in javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm using a contact form on my website, but lately I receive spam messages. I notice that these messages all start with `<b><a href=` (in the comment box). So if I could filter/block `<b><a href=` then perhaps I will not receive these messages anymore.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it's a matter of adding code to the code I have below. I'm a noob, so please forgive me. All help is very appreciated.

```
if (comment.get('value').length === 0) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(comment, commentError);
        } else {
            isValid = true;                     
            removeError(comment);
        }
```

Comment: What do they all start with?

Comment: You should take a look at regular expressions.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Sorry I didn't know some of the text didn't appear. You should be able to see it now.

Comment: add 
|| comment.get('value').indexOf("<b><a href=") >= 0
to the first if statement it will check for the string and return the location if found or -1 if not found

Comment: Marcelo, I added your code and it works! I ran a few tests and it really seems impossible now to send a message containing <b><a href=. So thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your code as follows, your `if` statement will return true so long as `<b><a href=` exists somewhere within it. If `<b><a href=` is not in the string, the index value returned will be -1, the `if` statement will evaluate to false and your `else` will be executed.

```
if (comment.get('value').indexOf("<b><a href=") !== -1) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(comment, commentError);
        } else {
            isValid = true;                     
            removeError(comment);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work. I can still send messages with <b><a href= in the comment box. What could be wrong?

Comment: I changed the != -1 to Marcelo's >= 0 and then it works. So thank you all for helping me out.

Comment: My apologies, i missed an equal sign. Make sure you upvote and mark answers as closed if you are satisfied with an answer!